# download webpages programically

Tags: python, html

I Want to Download This Page Using Python.
page link is https://tntenders.gov.in/nicgep/app?component=%24DirectLink&page=FrontEndTendersByOrganisation&service=direct&session=T&sp=S0g8N%2FzBGK2IUXzIfka6LnQ%3D%3D

page image is

[image: This The Page]

This is My Python code

```
import requests 
image_url = "https://tntenders.gov.in/nicgep/app?component=%24DirectLink&page=FrontEndTendersByOrganisation&service=direct&session=T&sp=S0g8N%2FzBGK2IUXzIfka6LnQ%3D%3D"

 # URL of the image to be downloaded is defined as image_url 
r = requests.get(image_url) # create HTTP response object 


with open("python_logo.html",'wb') as f: 

 
f.write(r.content)
```

After Downloaded This Page Cannot be shown

this page is shown here

[image]

What can i do for download the page??
Anyone Have Answer??
Help me!

Comment: How it is related to Java?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the session param from the link. New link: "https://tntenders.gov.in/nicgep/app?component=%24DirectLink&page=FrontEndTendersByOrganisation&service=direct".

Comment: Presumably because the server keeps the browsers latest chosen page as a session, and therefore, when removing the session, restores the state to original. You should be able to find the data by iterating over the table!